# launching angular and node separately but with connection to each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, deployment

So just for the testing purposes in production I had to split my frontend client written with angular 1.x and my node backend server code. Client uses api function provided by node but they are running on the different servers on my local machine. I set up my node server for running on port 5000 and when it's running my angular server gives me information that it has to move to port 5001 because port 5000 is already occupied.

How can I launch both of the servers and force them to share API functions on my local machine?

For the angular I use 'serve' -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

Comment: you want to run client-server (angular) and node-server (nodejs) on same port? You can not run two servers on same port :/

Comment: So technically it's impossible to run client and server side code separately on different servers but connecting to each other in terms of using API functions?

Comment: What constraint makes you to run both the servers on the same port? Will this do for you if both runs on the same port, but on different contexts, say UI runs on `localhost:5000/ui`, and API runs on `localhost:5000/api`?

Comment: You cannot make two applications to listen on the same port on the same ip. But you for sure can connect them. Thats what most larger projects do.  In a combined setup you wont access the individual apps through their ports directly, but use a reverse proxy like nginx which e.g. forwards everything starting with `/api` to your node app, and everything else to your angular app.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment, first tell me what you have and what you want? you have two serves and you want to run on same port? you can run two serves on same machine with different ports.

Comment: Wasif Khan -> I want to connect my angular and node code and let them cooperate with api functions when they are on the separate servers running on my local machine. They don't need to share the same port but cooperation is necessary. I've asked about that because my frontend cannot find api functions when they are on different ports and I receive error like "cannot find :5000/api/function"

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change port for your client side,

for this, edit your angular-cli.json

```
{
..............
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
            "port": 5001
        }
  }
.................
}
```

when you do ng serve , it will run your angularjs server on port 5001

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but since I couldn't add comments I had to write here.

If you are already using Vagrant then disregard the rest of this post.

This is just an option that may allow you to use both applications on the same port by setting up a vagrant instance.

Setup Vagrant for your node application. Configure the Vagrantfile to forward host:5001 to guest:5000.

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5001, host: 5000
```

You can continue hosting the angular application on your host(localhost) machine. Requests to your API can then be forwarded to the the vagrant instance.

If your angular app and api are already separated by a different domain, you can then update your host file on the local machine to rewrite domain requests to your vagrant machine.